# How to add a path folder when using ffmpeg?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

```
Execute(@"d:\D:\Captured Videos\ffmpeg.exe", "ffmpeg -r 1 -i file.mp4 -r 1 \"$filename%03d.bmp");
```

in the right side the parameters , how to add a folder for the video file name and a folder where to save the images ?

Comment: Unrelated: @"d:\D:\ - are you sure about that?

Comment: I tried this: Execute(@"d:\Captured Videos\ffmpeg.exe", "-r 1 -i m1.mp4 -r 1 d:\test\"$filename%03d.bmp"); I copied the m1.mp4 video file to the folder where the ffmpeg.exe file is but when I click the button nothing happens.   and how do i add a folder for the video file ? now i copied the video file to the folder of the ffmpeg.exe

Comment: Regarding the C# tag... note that `$filename` applies Linux shell syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You may use an absolute or relative path as the output option in all ffmpeg commands.

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -i file.mp4 -r 1 C:\Output\"$filename%03d.bmp
```

Comment: I tried this: Execute(@"d:\Captured Videos\ffmpeg.exe", "-r 1 -i m1.mp4 -r 1 d:\test\"$filename%03d.bmp"); I copied the m1.mp4 video file to the folder where the ffmpeg.exe file is but when I click the button nothing happens.

Comment: You should try run the command standalone in the terminal first